# iScroll 5: Click being detected while scrolling

Tags: javascript, iscroll

Using iScroll 5 for scrolling a list of elements. I am intending to handle click event on the list item but the problem is, every time I scroll (not click,) click handler is getting called too. Kindly suggest, how to stop click event being invoked while scrolling.

I am able to replicate the issue on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n422H/209/).

Here is how I am initializing iScroll object,

```
var scroll = new IScroll('#scroller', {
   bounce: false,
   momentum: true,
   mouseWheel: true,
   keyBindings: true,
   probeType: 3
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Using '`click: true`' in configuration fixes the problem.
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/n422H/210/) is the jsfiddle link where problem is fixed.